# Image save not working in formidable when using 'file' for form.on

Tags: node.js, image, file-upload, formidable

Following is the code which is working when I am using `form.parse` but it won't gets into `form.on('file', ...` Let me know what I am doing wrong here as I need to change the name of files before saving.

```
// CREATE
exports.upload = function (req, res) {

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.uploadDir = __dirname + '/upload';
    console.log("--FORM--");

    /*
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      console.log('received upload:\n\n');
      console.log(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });
    */
    form.on('file', function(field, file) {
        console.log("I am in file.");
        //rename the incoming file to the file's name
        //fs.rename(file.path, form.uploadDir + "/" + file.name);
    })


};
```

FYI - If I am using `form.parse` images are getting saved like `0382cb1bd421ee62b27dc431ab03270c` as I want to rename it which is not working when trying to do it via `form.on('file', ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `fileBegin` to change the name, though you need to **INCLUDE** `form.parse(req);` to save the image.

Working code -

```
form.on('fileBegin', function(name, file) {
    file.path = form.uploadDir + "/" + file.name;
})

form.parse(req);
```